# Passing UglifyJS options to Grunt Uglify

Tags: gruntjs

I'm trying to use [grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) with Grunt, which uses [UglifyJS](http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/) under the hood. Grunt-contrib-uglify has its own options that we may use, as below;

```
uglify: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      mangle: false
    },
    files: {
      'dist/build.min.js': ['dist/build.js']
    }
  }
},
```

However I need better customization that UglifyJS provides. But I can't figure out how to use them with grunt-contrib-uglify, The Github page just tells to refer to UglifyJS documentation for advanced configuration. Would appreciate if someone can point out how to use UglifyJS options. Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to customize?

Comment: For now I need to set `hoist_funs` to `false`. Just adding it to options in my code example above doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Generally this plugins have their own options and it's difficult to customize that. For that reason I want to know your customize because maybe the plugin could do the work for you.

Comment: It should be possible as the Github page says under Options: 'This task primarily delegates to UglifyJS2, so please consider the UglifyJS documentation as required reading for advanced configuration.'

Answer (score 1):

It's a tricky one, and I lost some time to this as well.

Read closely under the `grunt-contrib-uglify` [compress](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#compress) option documentation, and it says:

> Turn on or off source compression with default options. If an Object is specified, it is passed as options to UglifyJS.Compressor().

Said another way, you can directly set UglifyJS options via the `compress` option in your task.